# Detect selecting current selectedValue with React-Native Picker

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using React-Native's [Picker component](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html). Say I have the following:

```
export class someComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            someVal: 1
        };
    }

    onNewValueSelected = (newVal) => {
        Alert.alert('You selected the value: ' + newVal)
        this.setState({someVal: newVal});
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.someVal}
                    prompt="Select Some Value"
                    onValueChange={this.onNewValueSelected}
                    mode='dropdown'>
                    <Picker.Item label='one' value={1} />
                    <Picker.Item label='two' value={2} />
                    <Picker.Item label='three' value={3} />
                </Picker>
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

How would I detect that the currently selected value is selected in the modal? Say when this component first mounts the user selects 1. How would i know that they selected 1? `onValueChange` does not fire when the `selectedValue` is selected (at least on Android). I also don't see any way of creating a workaround for this component since I don't know a way of detecting when the Picker's modal or dropdown is opened and dismissed.

Maybe I just need to build a custom button and modal to handle this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you must set unique key for each, like this :

```
 on_type_Change(itemValue,itemIndex) {
    console.warn(itemValue,itemIndex);
}

<Picker
 selectedValue={this.state.value}
 onValueChange ={
 (itemValue, itemIndex) =>
 this.on_type_Change(itemValue, itemIndex)}
 mode='dropdown'>
 <Picker.Item label='one' value='1' key='uniquekey1'/>
 <Picker.Item label='one' value='2' key='uniquekey2'/>
 <Picker.Item label='one' value='3' key='uniquekey3'/>
</Picker>
```

or

```
on_type_Change(value) {
    console.warn(value);
}

<Picker
 selectedValue={this.state.value}
 onValueChange={this.on_type_Change.bind(this)}
 mode='dropdown'>
 <Picker.Item label='one' value='1' key='uniquekey1'/>
 <Picker.Item label='one' value='2' key='uniquekey2'/>
 <Picker.Item label='one' value='3' key='uniquekey3'/>
</Picker>
```